# node js elasticsearch requests with compression headers are rejected

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm using node js elasticsearch library and I'm indexing items. I'm trying to compress the traffic to Elasticsearch by adding a gzip header like so:

```
    elasticClient.index({
        body: body,
        index: index,
        type: type,
        id: id,
        headers: {
            'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'
        }
    }, function (err, resp) {

    });
```

Without the gzip header the request works fine, but when I include it I get a socket hang up. I've read that there is an elasticsearch configuration `http.compression: true`, but if I understood correctly, it refers to compression of ES responses and not to requests. Is there anything I can do to compress my requests? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The elasticsearch module internally manages the requests properly and takes care of issues like compression, connection pooling, persisting connections etc. So you don't have to think about these issues. You can verify it from their [codebase](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/blob/master/src/lib/connectors/http.js) if you wish

Comment: I took a look at the codebase in your link and there is a mentioning of "gzip" there, but it looks like it's in the context of an incoming request and not outgoing (by outgoing I mean that data is sent from the node library to the database. Could you please explain?